# Filtering calls to parent method

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I am extending a `Parent` class using composition instead of inheritance. I pass method calls from my `"Child"` to the `Parent` as shown in the code:

```
class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """Pass properties and method calls to Parent class"""
        result = getattr(self.obj, attr)
        return result
```

Now some method calls (ex `Parent.method()`) return a `Parent` instance. What I want is to be able to return a `Child` instance in these cases. I was thinking something like this would do it:

```
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """Pass properties and method calls to Parent class"""
        result = getattr(self.obj, attr)
        return Child(result)
```

but if fails with a: **TypeError: 'Child' object is not callable**. I also see that `result` has type `instancemethod` and not the actual result of the call to the method(which would be a `Parent` instance). What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you might override the variable Child, because the child instance should be callable.
Try looking for something like

```
Child = Child(some_argument)
```